# Symfony2 version 2.0.23, login with users from database always return: 'The presented password is invalid'

Tags: security, symfony, salt, provider

I'm trying to set up 2 firewall with 2 different providers and encoders in my security.yml that looks like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Devsign\UserBundle\Entity\AgentUser:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: true
        Devsign\UserBundle\Entity\PressUser:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: true

    providers:
        agent_secured_area:
            entity: {class: Devsign\UserBundle\Entity\AgentUser } # using a custom repository to login with username or email, details in AgentUserRepository.php

        press_secured_area:
            entity: {class: Devsign\UserBundle\Entity\PressUser, property: username }

    firewalls:
        agent_secured_area:
            pattern: /(it|en)/reserved/
            provider: agent_secured_area
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /it/reserved/login-check
                login_path: /reserved/login
            logout:
                path:   /reserved/logout
                target: /
        press_secured_area:
            pattern: /(it|en)/press/
            provider: press_secured_area
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /it/press/login-check
                login_path: /press/login
            logout:
                path:   /press/logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        agent_login:
            path: /reserved/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        agent_register:
            path: /reserved/register
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        agent_area:
            path: /(it|en)/reserved/.*
            roles: ROLE_AGENT
        press_login:
            path: /press/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        press_register:
            path: /press/register
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        press_area:
            path: /(it|en)/press/.*
            roles: ROLE_PRESS
```

I get no exception but when I try to login against agent_secured_area i get always: 'The presented password is invalid'.

I created the first user password and salt using this code in a controller:

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $user = new \Devsign\UserBundle\Entity\AgentUser();

    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $salt = $user->getSalt();
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword('grab', $salt);
    die("pwd: $password - salt: $salt");
```

And then i fill the database field password and salt with the echoed values.

Can someone spot the error?

**UPDATE 1**

I made some test setting in the config_dev.yml:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true
    verbose: true
```

1) I try to go to /it/reserved/info but it is access protected so I'm redirected correctly to /it/reserved/login

2) I try to login from /it/reserved/login posting the form to /it/reserved/login-check

3) Thanks to web_profile: intercepts_redirects: true I can see the debug toolbar in /it/reserved/login-check and I'm correctly authenticated with the correct Role: ROLE_AGENT. By the way looking in the doctrine section of the profiler I see two queries against my user table, the first one with parameter username NULL and a second one with the correct username.

4) Then I'm redirected to /it/reserved/info where for some reason I see a single query against my user table with parameter username NULL. Infact in /it/reserved/info I'm not authenticated anymore. So I'm redirected again to /it/reserved/login.

So I think the problem is that query with parameter username null, someone knows where it's coming from? Maybe from some misconfiguration on security.yml?